# PHP cURL options not being set

Tags: php, curl, centos, vagrant

I have a php REST client that calls a local tomcat REST server and have been using this for the last couple of years on a production server.

I've had to make some unrelated client side CSS changes and have had to build my development environment to test that they're ok before pushing to prod. Due to some changes with the version of vagrant I have installed I've had to change the vagrant box it uses and I think this is what's causing all the issues.

It appears when I make a cURL request something weird is happening and it's not creating the request correctly.

This is my client code (which is currently working on production):

```
class RestClient {

    private $baseEndpoint;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $siteCode;

    function __construct($baseEndpoint, $username, $password, $siteCode) {
        $this -> baseEndpoint = $baseEndpoint;
        $this -> username = $username;
        $this -> password = $password;
        $this -> siteCode = $siteCode;
    }

    public function get($endpoint) {
        //die($this -> baseEndpoint . $endpoint); //comment1
        $curlResource = curl_init($this -> baseEndpoint . $endpoint);
        curl_setopt_array($curlResource, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(                    
                "Accept:application/json",
                "Content-Type:application/json",
                "Site-Code:" . $this -> siteCode,
            ),
            CURLOPT_USERPWD => $this -> username . ":" . $this -> password
        ));         

        $curlResponse = curl_exec($curlResource);
        // echo curl_error($curlResource); //comment2 
        $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($curlResource); 
        // print_r($resultStatus); die(); //comment3

        $statusCode = $resultStatus['http_code'];

        if($statusCode != 200) {
            throw new Exception("500");
        }

        $restResponse = new Response();
        $restResponse -> setStatus($statusCode);
        $restResponse -> setEntity($curlResponse);

        return $restResponse;
    }
```

- If I uncomment comment1 I get what I expect - "http://localhost:8080/webApp/endpoint"
- If I uncomment comment2 I get "Failed to connect to ::1: Permission denied" which doesn't appear right at all... Where i've googled this error they all appear to show the request endpoint.
- If I uncomment comment3 I get "Array ( [url] => http://localhost:8080/webApp/endpoint [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0.000515 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => 127.0.0.1 [certinfo] => Array ( ) ) " which seems to show none of my options are being set.

Somes notes:

- When I run the curl request (curl --user user:password --header "site-code: london" http://localhost:8080/webApp/endpoint) I get the correct response.
- On the dev environment php version is 5.6.27, production is 5.6.26.
- OS versions are both CentOS release 6.8
- php cURL info is as follows:

`cURL support       enabled
 cURL Information   7.19.7
 Age                3
 Features
 AsynchDNS          No
 CharConv           No
 Debug              No
 GSS-Negotiate      Yes
 IDN                Yes
 IPv6               Yes
 krb4               No
 Largefile          Yes
 libz               Yes
 NTLM               Yes
 SPNEGO             No
 SSL                Yes
 SSPI               No
 Protocols          tftp, ftp, telnet, dict, ldap, ldaps, http, file, https, ftps, scp, sftp
 Host               x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
 SSL Version        NSS/3.21 Basic ECC
 ZLib Version       1.2.3
 libSSH Version     libssh2/1.4.2`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Copy and paste fail when doing some sanitisation. I'll update.

Comment: http_code = 0 smells like some sort of configuration stopping the curl request being sent.
Are you using SELinux? See the first comment here http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200234/linux-commandline-can-connect-but-webserver-or-php-cant-connect

https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans

`setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1`

Comment: I disabled SELinux and it appears to be exactly that. php once again provided no useful logging to help diagnose the problem!